# Backbone Marionette Views structure

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js, marionette

I have an application built on Backbone. Since it is getting more complex I am evaluating a migration to Marionette but I am not sure on how to structure my views.

The existing application views are structured in this way:

```
BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({ ... })
```

The BaseView is the root of all views. It basically has a *render* function with basic stuff like: template rendering, page localization, active menu selection, etc

```
ListView = BaseView.extend({ ... })
```

Here the *render* method contains common code for all lists like loading and use of DataTables plugin, common events for edititem, additem, deleteitem, etc

```
FormView = BaseView.extend({ ... })
```

It manages generic forms using the Backbone.ModelBinder plugin and handles the form validation.

All my application views extend from one of the above to improve code reusability. For example I have an AccountFormView that extends from FormView where I have just the specific logic (a few lines of code) to handle account information. All the common logic is inherited from the parents views.

How can I obtain something similar using Marionette Views?

Thanks,
Fabrizio

Comment: I'm using a lot Marionette lately and I did follow a pattern similar to wath you stated above. Just extend Marionette.ItemView for your base view and you're ok I guess!

Comment: I am not sure of your approach. What if I want use a CollectionView or a CompositeView? The don't extend from ItemView: CollectionView extends View & CompositeView extends CollectionView.

Comment: Well I have no needs actually to use a base Collection or Composite View, but if you have to you could just extend Marionette.View for your main view as its the base for all the other Marionette's Views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marionette's views are set up to handle the most common situations, and remove all the boilerplate code from solving these common problems:

- View: a base view that can be used to build other views
- ItemView: render a single model with a template
- CollectionView: render every model in a collection, using the specified `itemView`
- CompositeView: render a template as a wrapper around a collection view. supported nested / hierarchy structures

In your situation, it sounds like you'll be using a combination of these view types, depending on the specific scenario you're in. Instead of having a single view type to always extend from, though, you'll pick the one that makes the most sense for the current scenario and extend from that.

If you're looking for a way to add your own custom functionality to all views, that's also very easy - just add that feature tothe base Marionette.View or Backbone.View and it will be available to all Marionette views.

Be sure to check the documentation and code (it's split up in to many small files, so it's easy to read and understand) to see what methods Marionete provides for you, and what extension points it provides as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Derick. I followed your suggestion. My `Marionette.View` extension contains the code to localize the view. I have also extended  `Marionette.CompositeView` to enable DataTables initialization for all my CompositeViews. It works like a charm!